# PROC REPORT WITH MACRO

Tags: sas, sas-macro

I would like to create MACRO to produce a report (proc report) for each of datasets. For each report include title, "CYBOCS Compulsion Scale:Q6_#". Bold the line that has cycle 12 in it as cycle 12 is the primary endpoint. And using ODS RTF to output all reports to the personal drive
Here is the table look like:
[image]
Here is my code, I don't sure how to add bold line and how should I use ODS RTF to export reports

```
ODS RTF 
%MACRO diff(var=);
PROC REPORT DATA=table_&var.;
TITLE "CYBOCS COMPULSION SCALE: &var";

RUN;
%MEND diff;

options mprint mlogic;
%diff(var=q6_1a);
%diff(var=q6_1b);
%diff(var=q6_2);
%diff(var=q6_3);
%diff(var=q6_4);
%diff(var=q6_5);
%diff(var=q6_6);
%diff(var=q6_7);
%diff(var=q6_date);
```

Comment: Why have you not accepted *any* answer to your [past questions](https://stackoverflow.com/users/12936037/mino-liu) or even addressed comments? As original poster, you have these privileges regardless of reputation.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `compute` block and add your condition. You can use `call define()` to conditionally change a style based on your logic. For example, if we wanted to bold the row for every BMW in `sashelp.cars`:

```
proc report data=sashelp.cars;
    compute Make;
        if(Make = 'BMW') then call define(_ROW_, 'style', 'style=[font_weight=bold]');
    endcomp;
run;
```

[image]

Comment: %MACRO diff(var=);
PROC REPORT DATA=table_&var.;
    COMPUTE cycle;
        if(cycle = 12) then call define(_ROW_, 'style', 'style=[font_weight=bold]');
    ENDCOMP;
TITLE "CYBOCS COMPULSION SCALE: &var";
RUN;
%MEND diff;

Comment: I modified it like this but the report doesn't work

Comment: Can you post sample data so we can try and recreate your report? Is `cycle` a numeric or character variable? Try doing `if(cycle = '12')`.